# Changing bar colors in bar graph

Tags: excel, vba, graph, colors, bar-chart

I've created a VBA for Excel 2007 program that automatically creates bar graphs for ROI based on up to 52 different tabs in the active workbook. I'm close to done, and the *only* thing I cannot figure out is how to change the colors of the bargraphs.

The graphs are created in their own subfunction, called with a call like so.  Every variable changes around whenever it's called.

```
Call AddChartObject(1, 1, "Example", extraWeeks, weekDifference)
```

My sub that it calls looks like this.

```
Sub AddChartObject(j As Integer, k As Integer, passedChartTitle As String, xtraWks As Integer, ttlWks As Integer)

    Dim topOfChart As Integer

    topOfChart = 25 + (350 * j)

    'Adds bar chart for total sales

    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=375, Width:=475, Top:=topOfChart, Height:=325)
        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Consolidation").Range("$A$" & 3 + ((17 + xtraWks) _
            * j) & ":$C$" & (4 + ttlWks) + ((17 + xtraWks) * k))
        .Chart.ChartType = xl3DColumnClustered
        .Chart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelShow)
        .Chart.HasTitle = True
        .Chart.ChartTitle.Text = passedChartTitle & " Sales"
        .Chart.SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
        .Chart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelNone)
        .Chart.RightAngleAxes = True
    End With

End Sub
```

The RGB color I want to use on the SECOND series in the bar chart is (155, 187, 89), per marketing's wishes. I'm pretty sure there is a `.chart.????.???? = RGB (155, 187, 89)` command I can use in my `With` to set this, but I have spent far too much time trying to figure it out, only to come up with nothing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried

```
.Chart.SeriesCollection([index]).Interior.Color = RGB(155, 187, 89)
```

(where [index] is a placeholder for the series you want to change the color for)?

Comment: Perfect!  I was just missing the .interior. portion.  Thanks a ton Jubbles!

Answer (score 4):

It works for me ScottyStyles in a very similar situation, but only for the first series collection. I used the same right below that, and that was not changing the color of the SeriesCollection(2). That one is a linear set of datas.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate

    ActiveChart.ClearToMatchStyle

    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Interior.Color = RGB(85, 142, 213)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Interior.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

to change different bars inside a collection you can use:

```html
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(85, 142, 213)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192,0, 0)
...
```